# Handling multiple connections simultaneously with Node.js and PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a node.js server which I'm running with PM2 on a Red Hat system with 1 Core. The main purpose of the server is that users can upload data. At peak times around 75 users connect at the same time to the server and upload data (the data is uploaded in chunks of 1 MB and at the end concatenated by the server). Uploading data can take longer (around 10 minutes).

Currently, I'm starting the server using the following command

```
pm2 start server.js -i max -o ./logs/out.log -e ./logs/err.log
```

That means I'm starting it in cluster mode. I don't know if that is necessary with only 1 core. Should I instead just use fork mode (i.e. removing `-i max`)? Do I also have to use `pm2 scale server 75` so that I have 75 workers, i.e. one worker for each user? Or else, how can I scale it to 75 concurrent users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one core, will have the same efficency & only will use the core available. The cluster is useful if your computer/server has more than one core.

If you are asking for: will my server have 75 threads, one per user? no because NodeJS is single-threaded and will only use one thread for all the incoming requests.

The single threaded server is capable to hold 75 open connections concurrently

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way if I start the server with pm2 start server.js -i max --max-memory-restart 7G does this memory threshold hold for each single worker (process) or for all workers together?

Comment: Is for each one instance